# Animación no funciona en HTML agregado dinámicamente con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, material-design-lite

Estoy construyendo mi sitio web con [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io), el cual depende de lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

Cuando utilizo el formulario tiene un efecto que necesita de JavaScript. Todo carga perfecto si el formulario lo incluyo directamente en el HTML, pero al hacerlo mediante JavaScript deja de funcionar.

Lo que hago es esto:

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Get Started</a>
```

Y mi JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('business').innerHTML =  
    `<div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
            <h4>Formulario</h4>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
};
```

Este es un ejemplo del efecto que debe hacer el input:

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
   <h4>Formulario</h4>
   <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Ves en la consola *"myFunction is not defined"*?

Comment: En consola no muestra ningún error

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el efecto que debería hacer el formulario? Ejecutando tu código veo la animación del label, no sé si te refieres a eso.

Comment: Ese efecto debe hacer, pero cuando cargo input mediante JS no hace el efecto... puedes verlo en la siguiente página:

https://goo.gl/dP2OwO

Al hacer clic en el boton de la tarjeta se muestra el input cargado desde JS y pierde el efecto...

Comment: @DarwinJoseDeLaRosaDamian tu ejemplo funciona pero cuando lo unes con js deja de funcionar?

Comment: Todo funciona perfectamente, pero cuando hago la carga del "formulario" mediante JS deja de funcionar (No hace el efecto del label).

Comment: Asumo que es porque MDL *"inicializa"* ese tipo de animaciones al cargarse el documento. Es lo más probable. En ese caso tendrías que cargar nuevamente MDL mediante JavaScript (eliminar el `<script>` actual, crear un `<script>` nuevo, ponerle la url en eñ `src` y añadirlo al body).

Comment: PD: en tu próxima pregunta, utiliza un título descriptivo.

Comment: @DarwinJoseDeLaRosaDamian revisa mi respuesta, responde para saber si te ayuda, en caso contrario lo eliminare

Comment: Creo que mi respuesta es una solución elegante que te permitirá libertad a la hora de crear contenido dinámico cuando quieras y forzar la generación del MDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes forzar el [tratamiento el elemento del DOM que hará de contenedor](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works). Al ser modificado tras cargarse el DOM inicialmente (tras el evento `DOMContentLoaded`), hay que forzarlo sólo a ese elemento en particular:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var business = document.getElementById('business');
  /* Sólo se necesita si vamos a cambiar el aspecto previo */
  //componentHandler.downgradeElements(business);
  business.innerHTML =
    `<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    <h4>Formulario</h4>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`;
  /* Aquí viene la "magia", debemos forzar su tratamiento */
  componentHandler.upgradeElements(business);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div id="business">
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es ocultarlo, y luego volverlo visible haciendo click

```js
document.getElementById("business").style.visibility = "hidden";
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("business").style.visibility = "visible";
    
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
Ahora, cuando utilizo el formulario, tiene un efecto que necesita de JS. Todo carga perfecto si el formulario lo incluyo directamente al HTML, pero al hacerlo mediante JS... deja de funcionar.

Lo que hago es esto:
<div id="business">
`<div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
            <h4>Formulario</h4>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
</div>

<a onclick="myFunction()">Get Started</a>
```